# takes XXX km's trip? with XXX population?

Tags: grammaticality

Is the following sentence grammatical?

> It takes 16 km and 25 km’s trip to go to Bransdon (with 15,000 population) and Cransdon (with 29,000 population) respectively.

I have two doubts:

- Can one really say "it takes 16 km and 25 km's trip to go to ..."?

  First, I think one can only say "it takes xxx hours to go to xxx" (takes time, not distance)​
  Second, suppose one can say "it takes xxx km", is it correct to say "it takes a 16 km's trip"?​
- Can one really say "with xxx population"?

  I think one can only say "with a population of xxx". Is this correct?​

Answer (score 1):

However, you can say *it's a 16 km. trip to Bransdon (pop. 15,000).* It might be clearer to go on *… and a 25 km. trip to Cransdon...* rather than quoting both figures together and using *respectively.*

Comment: Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

You are correct. 'It takes' is most idiomatically used to refer to a time, so the statement implies that "*16 km and 25 km’s trip*" is the time to go to *Bradson...and Cransdon...*

For example, '*It takes 5 minutes to go to Sara's house and Ana's house*; this means Sara's house and Ana's house are 5 minutes away from the current location. Now replace the *5 minutes* with "*16 km and 25 km’s trip*" and *Sara's house and Ana's house* with *Bradson...and Cransdon...*. You can see that it does not make any sense.

'With' is a very context dependent preposition. *15000 population* and *29000 population* are meant to modify the respective towns, and so it is best to say *...Bradson, which has a population of 15000, and Crandson, which has a population of 29000*. Saying *...to go to Bradson (with population of 15000)* sounds like you went to Bradson with 15000 people, similar to saying 'I went to Alaska with my girlfriend'. The parentheses makes the situation slightly better I suppose, but I would always use a relative pronoun (e.g. which, who etc.) to refer to an inherent quality in a noun.

Comment: Thank you! That has cleared up my doubts.